# Find the ID of the window which generates alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to find out the id of the IE window that generates alert boxes?  I assume it is the document or window itself.

Either simple html or jQuery can be used.

I tried something like:

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

but to no avail.

Ultimately I want to find out the ID of the window/document which generates javascript alerts so I can override it.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the document title? Or `window.name`? Or `document.body.id`? Not sure what "ID of the window" means.

Comment: I wanted to override javascript alerts, and I assume that it comes from the actual browser itself.  But I'm not sure whether that means it starts from window or document, so I just threw the question in the air for clarification. HTH.

Comment: See my answer, there's a link that tells you how to do it!

Comment: @ Mike Gleason jr Couturier: thanks.  I'm currently looking at how to just override the specific alert, since I want to confirm that a particular alert box has been overriden as part of my unit test.

Comment: Cool! Just look at the link then!

Comment: yeah I want to do something like if (windows.alert().text == 'specific text') override this alert.  Haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the document did not specified an ID attribute for the body, there's not much info you can gather... the html tag doesn't specify an ID attribute either...

You must build a mechanism yourself to identify your windows..

See the jQuery data() to attach a custom "property" to a DOM object if you want to keep your windows handles somewhere.

To override the alert function, see my response to this question: [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert/1729684#1729684)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need to do this but if you mean that you want to override the alert function it's pretty easy:

```
alert = function() {
    // do some custom stuff here
};
```