# Can you alter a Javascript function after declaring it?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, wrapper, modifier

Let's say I have `var a = function() { return 1; }`. Is it possible to alter `a` so that `a()` returns `2`? Perhaps by editing a property of the `a` object, since [every function is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function)?

**Update:** Wow, thanks for all the responses. However, I'm afraid I wasn't looking to simply reassign a variable but actually edit an existing function. I am thinking along the lines of how you can combine [partial functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/PartialFunction.html) in Scala to create a new `PartialFunction`. I am interested in writing something similar in Javascript and was thinking that the existing function could perhaps be updated, rather than creating an entirely new `Function` object.

Comment: Why would you not just assign a new function to a that returned 2?

Comment: Because this wouldn't update references to the function held elsewhere.

Comment: It might be over a decade later, but it's still something folks are going to think about doing, and so to benefit all of those who find this question, it's still worth accepting https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539482/740553 as the only correct answer. This cannot be done, unless you're using a spec-violating JS engine.

Answer (score 52):

You can do all kinds of fun stuff with javascript, including redefining functions:

```js
let a = function() { return 1; }
console.log(a()); // 1
    
// keep a reference
let old = a;
   
// redefine
a = function() {
  // call the original function with any arguments specified, storing the result
  const originalResult = old.apply(old, arguments);
  // add one
  return originalResult + 1;
};

console.log(a()); // 2
```

Voila.

Edit: Updated to show this in a crazier scenario:

```js
let test = new String("123");
console.log(test.toString()); // logs 123
console.log(test.substring(0)); // logs 123
String.prototype.substring = function(){ return "hahanope"; }
console.log(test.substring(0)); // logs hahanope
```

You can see here that even though "test" is defined first, and we redefine substring() afterwards, the change still applies.

Side note: you really should reconsider your architecture if you're doing this...you're going to confuse the crap out of some poor developer 5 years down the road when s/he's looking at a function definition that's supposed to return 1, but seems to always return 2....

Comment: This does not redefine the function. It assigns an entirely new function to the variable which referenced the old one. References to the original function elsewhere won't be updated.

Comment: @hashchange: touche. That said, the fact that it's simply a "var" reference is immaterial here. If you wanted to change, say, a core function in your application, you would simply modify the prototype. The concept still applies.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was looking around hoping to find a way to save any current window.onload function then append my own (assigning window.onload overwrites any previous function).

Answer (score 49):

So you want to modify the code of a function directly, in place, and not just reassign a different function to an existing variable.

I hate to say it, but as far as I have been able to figure it out - and I have tried -, it can't be done. True, a function is an object, and as such it has methods and properties which can be tweaked and overwritten on the object itself. Unfortunately, the function body is not one of them. It is not assigned to a public property.

The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) lists the properties and methods of the function object. None of them gives us the opportunity to manipulate the function body from the outside.

That's because [according to the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2), the function body is stored in the internal `[[Code]]` property of the function object, which can't be accessed directly.

Comment: I tried hard, and couldn't get it to happen either. Even Proxy doesn't really let you hook into the original function, since to intercept you have to call the new proxy.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The spec has never allowed writable access to a declared Function's `[[Code]]`, only read access via `toString()`.

Answer (score 43):

I used something like this to modify an existing function whose declaration was not accessible to me:

```
// declare function foo
var foo = function (a) { alert(a); };

// modify function foo
foo = new Function (
  "a",
  foo.toSource()
    .replace("alert(a)", "alert('function modified - ' + a)")
    .replace(/^function[^{]+{/i,"")  // remove everything up to and including the first curly bracket
    .replace(/}[^}]*$/i, "")  // remove last curly bracket and everything after<br>
);
```

Instead of toSource() you could probably use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource) to get a string containing the function's declaration. Some calls to replace() to prepare the string for use with the Function Constructor and to modify the function's source.

Comment: Interesting. No way to do it without going through strings, though? Bummer.

Comment: toSource doesn't work on IE and Chrome. And this is simpler to get the function code: `foo.toString().match(/{([\s\S]*)}/)[1]`. Also @prm1001 you should accept this as the correct answer. It did helped me too

Comment: thanks hmundt and Bubu Daba.

Correct, apparently must use strings.

Comment: I want to change content of a generated function (by Animate). This would be correct answer. But as of 2016, toSource is still not (or already not) supported. Also, this uses regex, where it's not needed and indexOf/lastIndexOf can be used. [This uses toString() and no regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472370/how-can-dynmically-change-a-line-of-a-javascript-function/#answer-3472440). Also consider [proxying it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert/#answer-1729684)

Comment: Funny thing, this is the essence of shims.  When a browser doesn't implement a function, or does so poorly, you set up built-in objects with your own custom function, so your script always has a uniform environment.  I wish there was finer grained control than string replace on the entire function.  But at least the function reference appears to remain valid after replacement and reparse, so that is handy.

Answer (score 21):

```
let a = function() { return 1; }
console.log(a()) // 1

a = function() { return 2; }
console.log(a()) // 2
```

technically, you're losing one function definition and replacing it with another.

Answer (score 17):

How about this, without having to redefine the function:

```
var a = function() { return arguments.callee.value || 1; };
alert(a()); // => 1
a.value = 2;
alert(a()); // => 2
```

Comment: Agree as each time you redefine it, you're overwriting old reference, without changing other existing references, which sux indeed.

Comment: This is the only correct answer on here at the moment - the only one that actually affects the function, and not creating a new one.

Comment: arguments.callee is deprecated, unfortunately

Comment: If you name the function, you can use its name on the body as a reference... 
const a = function myFunction() { return myFunction.value || 1 }

Answer (score 13):

I am sticking to jvenema's solution, in which I don't like the global variable "old". It seems better to keep the old function inside of the new one:

```
function a() { return 1; }

// redefine
a = (function(){
  var _a = a;
  return function() {
  // You may reuse the original function ...
  // Typical case: Conditionally use old/new behaviour
    var originalResult = _a.apply(this, arguments);
  // ... and modify the logic in any way
    return originalResult + 1;
    }
})();
a()  // --> gives 2
```

Answer (score 6):

All feasible solutions stick to a "function wrapping approach".
[The most reliable amongst them seems to be the one of rplantiko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580937/2627243).

Such function wrapping easily can be abstracted away. The concept / pattern itself might be called "Method Modification". Its implementation definitely belongs to `Function.prototype`. It would be nice to be backed
one day by standard prototypal method modifiers like `before`, `after`, `around`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally`.

As for the aforementioned example by *rplantiko* ...

```js
function a () { return 1; }

// redefine
a = (function () {
  var _a = a;
  return function () {
    // You may reuse the original function ...
    // Typical case: Conditionally use old/new behaviour
    var originalResult = _a.apply(this, arguments);
    // ... and modify the logic in any way
    return originalResult + 1;
  };
})();

console.log('a() ...', a()); // --> gives 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... and making use of `around`, the code would transform to ...

```js
function a () { return 1; }

console.log('original a ...', a);
console.log('a() ...', a()); // 1


a = a.around(function (proceed, handler, args) {
  return (proceed() + 1);
});

console.log('\nmodified a ...', a);
console.log('a() ...', a()); // 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
(function(d){function f(a){return typeof a==e&&typeof a.call==e&&typeof a.apply==e}function g(a,b){b=null!=b&&b||null;var c=this;return f(a)&&f(c)&&function(){return a.call(b||null!=this&&this||null,c,a,arguments)}||c}var e=typeof d;Object.defineProperty(d.prototype,"around",{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:g});Object.defineProperty(d,"around",{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:function(a,b,c){return g.call(a,b,c)}})})(Function);
</script>
```

Comment: This was basically what the function `wrap()` of the Prototype framework afforded / still affords.  http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/wrap/
Don't know whether there is some feature of this kind in the current ESx version

Comment: Doesn't this just create a new function every time it's invoked? It's just generalizing the `a = newFunction` approach.

Comment: Exactly, and the first 2 introducing paragraphs of this answer also do emphasize this fact.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **Clear Example** based on a control timepicker `eworld.ui`
www.eworldui.net

Having a TimePicker `eworld.ui` where JavaScript is unreachable from outside, you can't find any js related to those controls. So how can you add a onchange event to the timepicker ?

There is a `js` function called when you `Select` a time between all the options that the control offer you. This function is:  `TimePicker_Up_SelectTime`

First you have to copy the code inside this function.

Evaluate...quikwatch...`TimePicker_Up_SelectTime.toString()`

```
function TimePicker_Up_SelectTime(tbName, lblName, divName, selTime, enableHide, postbackFunc, customFunc) {
    document.getElementById(tbName).value = selTime;
    if(lblName != '')
        document.getElementById(lblName).innerHTML = selTime;
    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if(enableHide)
        TimePicker_Up_ShowHideDDL('visible');
    if(customFunc != "")
        eval(customFunc + "('" + selTime + "', '" + tbName + "');");
    eval(postbackFunc + "();");
}
```

Now

Using the code that you have saved before reassign the same source code but add whatever you want..

```
TimePicker_Up_SelectTime = function (tbName, lblName, divName, selTime, enableHide, postbackFunc, customFunc) {
    document.getElementById(tbName).value = selTime;
    if (lblName != '')
        document.getElementById(lblName).innerHTML = selTime;
    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if (enableHide)
        TimePicker_Up_ShowHideDDL('visible');
    if (customFunc != "")
        eval(customFunc + "('" + selTime + "', '" + tbName + "');");
    eval(postbackFunc + "();");

    >>>>>>>  My function  >>>>>   RaiseChange(tbName);
}
```

I've added My Function to the function so now I can simulate an onchange event when I select a time.

RaiseChange(...) could be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging javascript and want to see how changes to the code affects the page, you can use this Firefox extension to view/alter javascripts:

Execute JS firefox extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1729

Answer (score -1):

```js
const createFunction = function (defaultRealization) {
  let realization = defaultRealization;

  const youFunction = function (...args) {
    return realization(...args);
  };
  youFunction.alterRealization = function (fn) {
    realization = fn;
  };

  return youFunction;
}

const myFunction = createFunction(function () { return 1; });
console.log(myFunction()); // 1

myFunction.alterRealization(function () { return 2; });
console.log(myFunction()); // 2
```

Comment: Can you add a short description to your answer explaining your code and how it answers the OP's question?

Answer (score -2):

Can you not just define it again later on?  When you want the change try just redefining it as:

```
a = function() { return 2; }
```