# assigning a function(with arguments) a variable name? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've decided to teach myself functional programming.

I've submitted all of my assignments whilst maintaining the rules of functional programming, and my instructor is totally fine with it. To grab inputs, I've been doing something like this:

```
var getWidth = function(){
  return prompt("What is the width?");
};
```

This works fine but it could be something simpler, like:

```
var getWidth = prompt("What is the Width?");
```

The problem with this, is when I call the function `getWidth()`, it simply runs the function once and assigns it to the `getWidth` variable. But that's not what I want, I want it to run `prompt("What is the Width?")` every time `getWidth()` is called. I've tried to search for it, but I'm not really entirely sure how to phrase it. Google's useful, if you know how to use it.

Comment: That's the difference between *defining* a function and *calling* a function.

Comment: Checkout this answer. This might be of some help. [Can you alter a Javascript function after declaring it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136522/can-you-alter-a-javascript-function-after-declaring-it)

Comment: Well, in functional programming with pure functions there would not be much of a difference, but **`prompt` is not pure**. Therefore it matters how often you call it or not.

Comment: @Bergi Didn't know that, I'll have to look at the individual functions more in depth. At the moment I'm just learning, so I'll forgive myself for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the OP might be looking for, is the lambda functional shorthand. It's a really simple bit of code, that let's you right functions much shorter. It's usually, used for anonymous functions, but it could easily be re-purposed here. For example:

```
function getWidth(){
   return prompt("What is the width?");
}
```

Would be reduced to:

```
var getWidth() = () => prompt("What is the width?");
```

Note that the value of prompt is returned automatically, so you don't need to add `return` to your code.

Parameters could also be specified if desired, like this:

```
var getWidth = (x) => prompt(x);
```

And if you use arguments this way, then the `()` are optional. This would work too:

```
var getWidth() = x => prompt(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
var hm = window.prompt.bind(window, "simpler?");
console.log(hm());
```

Answer (score 1):

> it could be something simpler, like:

You cannot "simplify" a function

```
var a = function onePlusTwo() {
  return 1 + 2;
};
```

by writing

```
var a = 1 + 2;
```

The two do entirely different things.

The first **defines** a function (meaning, does **not** execute it), and assigns the function to the variable `a`. The function can then be called with `a()`, which will **evaluate** to `3`, since that is the return value of the function:

```
alert(a() * 2)  // 6
```

The second (`var a = 1 + 2;`) merely executes the code which you had in the body of the function. Executing it assigns the result of `1 + 2` to the variable a. This code is "re-usable" only by copying and pasting it elsewhere in your program.

So if you want to define functionality and re-use it, you have no choice but to define it as a function. That's what functions are for!

If you want to take a function and make another function you can use to call that function later, with or without some arguments, then as mentioned in another answer, you can use `bind`, as in `var a = prompt.bind(window, "What is the width?");`, and then call it with `a()`. But this is essentially the same as writing the function out in the way you did in the first example, and is a little bit less readable.

By the way, none of this is "functional programming". Functional programming does not mean just using functions; all programs do that. Functional programming refers to a style of programming involving manipulating, combining, dynamically creating, and passing around functions.

Comment: Okey dokey. Thanks. Now that I think about it, just making getWidth a string and passing it to prompt would work fine for my purposes. I am aware that it's not function, that was mostly just background.  I've done lot's of manipulating with functions, though dynamic creating is new to me. I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify your function this way. By the first method:

```
var getWidth = function(){
  return prompt("What is the width?");
};
```

You are returning an executable function, and assigned the function reference to a variable getWidth. However in the second one:

```
var getWidth = prompt("What is the Width?");
```

You are returning the result of the function window.prompt.