# How do I make sure that that I can make many balls animate within my draw function in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I am trying to run my code so that the multiple balls apear on the screen. After debugging I found that my **circleX** and **circleY** variable is not appearing in my code. **circlX** is the location of ball I want **CircleX** and **circleY** passed into the **drawManyBalls** function and **drawBallsMoving** function.

I'm not sure why it's not running my code or not seeing these variables.

I tried using an apply method to try to apply the **circlX** and **circleY** variables, where I would run that function and then apply it to another function. like seen in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136522/can-you-alter-a-javascript-function-after-declaring-it/19522444#19522444).

I also tried running a function within a function and that didn't work.

check out my code on Js Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/Blummer92/kuj2tzy4/1/**

## Java Script

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//every frame has been drawn to make it appear that the ball is moving
//this sets the moving ball
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//every frame has been drawn to make it appear that the ball is moving
//this sets the moving ball
let circleX = canvas.width / 2;
let circleY = canvas.height - 30;
var ballRadius = 10;

// newly spawned objects start at Y=25
var spawnLineY = 25;

// spawn a new object every 1500ms
var spawnRate = 1500;

// set how fast the objects will fall
var spawnRateOfDescent = 0.5;

// when was the last object spawned
var lastSpawn = -1;

// this array holds all spawned object
var objects = [];

// save the starting time (used to calc elapsed time)
var startTime = Date.now();

var dx =2;
var dy =-2;

function spawnRandomObject(object) {

    // select a random type for this new object
    var t;

    // About Math.random()
    // Math.random() generates a semi-random number
    // between 0-1. So to randomly decide if the next object
    // will be A or B, we say if the random# is 0-.49 we
    // create A and if the random# is .50-1.00 we create B

    if (Math.random() < 0.50) {
        t = "red";
    } else {
        t = "blue";
    }

    // create the new object
    var object = {
        // set this objects type
        type: t,
        // set x randomly but at least 15px off the canvas edges
        x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15,
        // set y to start on the line where objects are spawned
        y: spawnLineY,
    }

    // add the new object to the objects[] array
    objects.push(object);
}

let drawBall = (circleX, circleY) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  let dimentions = ballRadius => {
    ctx.arc(circleX, circleY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.closePath();
  };

var drawManyBall = () => {
    let CircleX = spawnRandomObject.object.X;
    let CicleY = spawnRandomObject.object.Y;
    drawBall();
    drawBall.dimentions.apply(this, circleX, circleY); // use .apply() to call it
    ctx.moveTo(circleX, circleY + spawnLineY);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, spawnLineY);
  };
let draw = () => {
  circleX += dx;
  circleY += dy;

// get the elapsed time
var time = Date.now();

// see if its time to spawn a new object
if (time > lastSpawn + spawnRate) {
  lastSpawn = time;
  spawnRandomObject();
}

// request another animation frame
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// runs a loop that
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  var object = objects[i];

  //should I be using cirlce why as a part of my method?
  object.Y += spawnRateOfDescent;
  let CircleX = object.X;
  let CicleY = object.Y;

  var drawBallsmoving = () => {
    drawBall();
    drawBall.dimentions.apply(this, circleX, circleY);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
  };
}
```

During Debugging my output was

```
drawBall: (circleX, circleY) => {…}
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142) at <anonymous>:1:1]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142) at <anonymous>:1:1]
length: 2
```

Comment: In your post you reference `CirclX` and `CircleYT` (neither of which appear in your code). The code contains references to `circleX` and `circleY`, as well as `CircleX` and `CicleY` which are never actually used. So it appears there are quite a few typos.

Comment: @djfdev meant to make it say `circleY` and `circleX` my bad

Comment: But before even getting to any of that, your code is not running because the `draw` function is undefined in the global scope.

Comment: are you refering to `let draw = () => {};`

Comment: There is a `draw` function defined on line 126. The last line of your code makes a reference to that function, but it is not defined within the same scope and therefore is inaccessible.

Comment: Check the console to see the resulting error.

Comment: what am i concoling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201979/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-djfdev).