# How to modify all references to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible to modify all references to an anonymous function so that invocations from other objects reflects the changes?

Below is an example of a situation where obj1.name and obj2.name both points to the same function, but since the function is passed by value when creating obj2.name = obj1.name, changes in obj1.name doesn't affect obj2.name.

In this example, I would like to modify that function so that it returns 'edited' for all objects.

```
//This two declarations are part of the original code that I cannot modify.
let obj1 = {
    name: function() { return 'original'; }
}
let obj2 = {
    name: obj1.name
}
// obj1.name() >> 'original'
// obj2.name() >> 'original'

// At this point, I want to modify the returned value.
obj1.name = function() { return 'edited'; }
// obj1.name() >> 'edited'
// obj2.name() >> 'original'
```

Comment: No. Having it as part of multiple objects is a bad design (as you've discovered) and you should change it rather than try to come up with a hacky solution.

Comment: I'm confused. You said *"This two declarations are part of the original code that I cannot modify"*, but you are modifying them here: `obj1.name = function() { return 'edited'; }`. So, what are the rules? If you can change `obj1.name` you surely can change `obj2.name`, as suggested in the current answer.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/2136522 will be helpful?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm trying to simplify a more complex situation where I have several objects pointing to an anonymous function. I want to modify that function for all the objects that might call it (I have no idea how many objects might be calling that function, so I have to directly attack the function)

Comment: If the objects already exists, and they each contains their own anonymous function, then by definition there's no way you can change what those functions do unless you can enumerate over that list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. That way obj2.name is a function also.

If you wanted obj2.name to be a property, then after obj1.name was changed you would need something to watch that and upddate obj2.name. So its probably easier to use a method.

```
let obj1 = {
    name: function() { return 'original'; }
}
let obj2 = {
    name: function() { return obj1.name() }
}
```

Comment: I didn't explain myself enough, the declaration of both obj1 and obj2 is part of the original code, I want to modify the function having that specific declaration.

Comment: ahh do you mean like this
const someFunction = () => {}

let obj1 = { name : someFunction}
let ob2 = { name : someFunction }

someFunction = () => { console.log("do something else"}

Comment: Yes exactly! The problem is that my function is anonymous so I cannot (or don't know how) modify it directly

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, each time `obj1.name()` is invoked, it then gets which ever version of `someFunction` is current at the time, as opposed to assigning once and never checking again

```
let someFunction = () => "original"

let obj1 = {
  name:  () => someFunction()
}

let obj2 = {
  name:  () => someFunction()
}

console.log(obj1.name())
console.log(obj2.name())

someFunction = () => "edited"

console.log(obj1.name())
console.log(obj2.name())
```

Comment: Okay got it, the additional function which returned a function was not at all necessary

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's a good idea but still I can't modify the function that way because in my case the function doesn't have a name (function(){...)