# Overriding native function?

Tags: javascript, dom

The native `document.createElement()` is silly-stupid (it takes only a tag name and no attributes). How come I can't override it? How come this doesn't work?

```
var originalFunction = document.createElement;

document.createElement = function(tag, attributes) {
    var element = originalFunction(tag);

    if (attributes) {
        for (var attribute in attributes) {
            element.setAttribute(attribute, attributes[attribute]);
        }
    }

    return element;
};
```

The problem is that browsers blow up when you try to replace a native function. Since `document` is not a JavaScript primitive, you can't create a prototype for it either. WTF.

Comment: I think `document.createElement(..)` doesn't think much of you either.

Comment: Why not just create and use your own function instead of overriding native functions?

Comment: @KennethJ Because some people still try to create a Standardization library or try to execute validation code when an Element is created on the DOM, without having to create Namespaces and other stuff.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I can tell the problem is that a call to the `document.createElement()` function even when referenced has to be from the document. So modify your code:

```
var element = originalFunction.call(document, tag);
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW (informational): you can override "native" methods, in some cases, and in some browsers at least. Firefox lets me do this:

```
document.createElement = function(f) { alert(f); };
```

Which then does as you expect when invoked. But your whole block of code above throws an error, at least via Firebug.

Philosophically, you should be able to do this. You can certainly, say, redefine methods on the Array object, etc. But the window (DOM) methods are not covered by ECMAScript, and so they're probably allowed to be implementation-dependent. And of course, they are this way for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the method in your own function- write it the way you want, and never write document.createElement again....

```
    document.create= function(tag, parent, attributes){
     tag= document.createElement(tag);
     for(var p in attributes){
      if(p== 'css') tag.style.cssText= attributes.css;
      else if(p== 'text') tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(attributes.text));
      else tag[p]= attributes[p];

     }
    if(parent) parent.appendChild(tag);
     return tag;
    }

document.create('p',document.body,{css:'font-style:italic',className:'important',title:'title',
text:'whatever text you like'});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot override native methods for security reasons. For non-native methods it's no problem at all.

Comment: In some browsers you can override some native methods. I haven't yet encountered a native method that can't be overridden.

Comment: @JimBlackler - FYI MSIE's console.<whatever> cannot be overriden, but not for security reasons, just because they could do it (see, console isn't covered by ES :) Microsoft at it again, lol)

Answer (score 0):

The proxy pattern mentioned at [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert) should work for this.

It's mentioned in jquery docs but doesn't look like it actually has a dependency on jQuery.

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Proxy%5FPattern

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to override that, however you can do some hack around if you not affraid of passing non conventional parameter(s) to a native function. So the thing about createElement that its ment to be the part of the XML DOM, thus you can create whatever tagname you want. And here is the trick, if you pass your attributes as a part of the first parameter (the tagname), separating them with the delimiters of your choise, and then listening to the onchange event of the DOM and if your delimiters are presented in any tag, replace them with the proper markup, using RegExp for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
document.constructor.prototype.createElement = _ => `P for "pwned"`;

console.log(document.createElement("P"));
```