# Set Button.type to "button" by default

Tags: javascript, button, overriding

I'd like it that when I create a new button, it's type is set to "button" by default. Here's what I've tried:

```
var createE = document.createElement;
document.createElement = (str) => {
  let elem = createE(str);
  if (str.toLowerCase() == "button") {
    elem.type = "button";
  }
}
```

I am getting an "illegal invocation" exception at `let elem = createE(str);` (in Chrome)

Is there a way to override the prototype or otherwise achieve this other than using a function in every place I'd otherwise use createElement("Button")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding native function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346082/overriding-native-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the method using a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) like this:

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PTAEGkFNIB1BDUAnSAzSKB2BjSoAuA9gQBZ6FICWA5pZvADah2jbwDOeAnoQK6gB3eJnwFiKdkRTNRDePgwAuAFDZCmSaxTzIAUQaQAtpBEB5KrXpMAvKAAmhbL2MiAdNm0L9Rk-gDcyiCgAILIaBgmuGKkeMb4JIR2gpTxMaAAboy85KigAAbxlOx5oABGfJhJRDLsoDDwWKKEpQBWkNj4Kmoaoh6QOt4uorZ9AwZD5jR0jK6ldHYAFA5OQwCUAcrLzr7unnrjvqC2mJACoAAKSIQAHlxLjttuo14HIgA0oADeyqAIMDAMO4AfXwDWokHwHxBJCKwSQ1A+AG1QdQAHLwYwfQgwfCUdTsAC6qy+P1+rHxokgr2GWn6Lx8IgWKPRmNA2Nx+PWpN+lFyCypDPwrmZGLw1nFoAARAAhACqABV5aZUZLid8yWSBUNXJx8MF8PgqKVeAoFpL8FwYJBJR9JcaDepVQENQBfblhfC8JCYUBa3zO0Aut7KF1c1QUsr4H22Lba577QVm+1ETBO8MaQgGVwMQjUBalKPCy2QD4FzCuPgKJAACXlAFkADLrUBBO0mlOSqUAHmT6gIxesAHJe5hBwA+LvAEdjyXKIA)

```js
// Keep a reference to the original in case you want to restore it later:
const createElementOriginal = document.createElement;
// A reference to the method with the value of `this` bound to its parent object:
const createElement = createElementOriginal.bind(document);

document.createElement = new Proxy(document.createElement, {
  apply(_target, _thisArg, [tagName, options]) {
    const element = createElement(tagName, options);
    if (element.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      element.setAttribute("type", "button");
    }
    return element;
  },
});

const btn = document.createElement("button");
console.log(btn.type, btn.outerHTML); // "button" "<button type='button'></button>"
```

Comment: I had no idea that proxy even existed, let alone that you could use it here! This is some serious hacking... Thank you for this!