# Block javascript Alert box

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website using extensively javascript. The code I'm working on also rely on other *big* javascript libs. The thing is that somewhere in these libraries, some alert box are poping.

I was wondering if there are some way to disable the javascript alert box *on the fly* and re-enable it later.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the old `alert` function, to a variable.

```
_alert=alert;
```

And then set the old `alert` to either `null` a custom function.

```
alert=function(){};
/*or*/
alert = null;
```

To restore the original version of `alert` simply reverse step 1.

```
alert=_alert
```