# Why does the alert box block all tabs in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I remember each tab in chrome is an individual window, then why does the alert box in any tab blocks the other tabs?

Do all the tabs share the same javascript engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these links...

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89579

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3658

[Block javascript Alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587134/block-javascript-alert-box)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've checked some similar links before but they did not mention the cause of blocking. Your first link says the blocking is caused by windows api. Does that mean all tabs in chrome share the same process so the api blocks them all ?

Comment: In the chrome://memory-redirect/ i see not all tabs share the same process. Can not figure out why are all tabs blocked ?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome fixed this in 2017.  Now, when a tab alerts, other tabs will not block.

See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456