# Overriding window.alert and passing multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, window, alert

I am trying to override the window.alert to pass multiple parameters.

Please someone explain me why for/in inherits Array.prototype.tester's body into list?

Thank you very much.

```
Array.prototype.tester = function() {
    return 'tester';
}

window.alert = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var list = [];

    for (var i in args) {
        list.push(args[i]);
    }

    return list.join(', '); // WHY???? alerts: "arg1, arg2, function () { return "tester"; }"
    //return args.join(', '); // alerts: "arg1, arg2" expected.
}

alert('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [casablanca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381345/casablanca), `for in` iterates over properties defined by yourself that are in the objects prototype chain.

To fix this, use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
for (var i in args) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        list.push(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for-in` iterates over all enumerable properties of an object, which includes anything defined in the object or its prototypes. Most built-in functions are declared non-enumerable, so they don't appear during normal iteration. ECMAScript 5 allows you to define your own properties as non-enumerable, although I'm not sure which browsers support this:

```
function testerFunc() {
  return 'tester';
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'tester', {
  value: testerFunc,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.alert` is a constant function, you cannot redefine it directly:

[Javascript overriding alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Comment: @loentar the link says that it's possible by using a Proxy and not directly.