# Is is possible to transform all js alert messages in modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an old site and i would avoid searching&replacing and i was wondering if it is possible to reaplce all alert massages function

```
alert('some msg');
```

with a jquery modal window...

i'm not asking how to do the modal window but if i can create a protoype to replace the function alert..

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since the problem in this question (creating something modal that blocks in JavaScript) is quite different from that thread.

Comment: @Matti I think the OP is asking exactly for what the duplicate deals with but you have a point - a jQuery "modal" window won't be modal, so it will deviate  differently from `alert()`'s native behaviour

Comment: @Pekka: Judging by the post ("avoid searching&replacing") the thing he wants is something that works *identically* to the built-in `alert` function but looks different. I don't think the other thread has anything about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override alert:

```
 window.alert = function(txt) {
    // Custom handler here
 }
```

Note that this will be non blocking though. Code after alert will execute without waiting.

Answer (score 3):

`alert` is special in the fact that it blocks until the user responds to the popup. Generally in JS this is a big no-no, because if you block, you'll block the entire user interface. This precludes using a jQuery modal popup as a direct replacement for `alert`. You need to modify the software to use callbacks instead of synchronous alerts. (Most of) JS is event-based and single-threaded, and there isn't really a way around that.

There is a function called [showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759(VS.85).aspx) which shows a modal popup window (the kind we all hate), but that's pretty much it. It originated from IE, but as Pekka pointed out it's also implemented in Firefox 3 or newer and based on a quick Google search Webkit seems to have some support for it as well. It's still not a neat in-page popup though.

Comment: ShowModalDialog is available in Firefox since V3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog