# Disable alert();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code that is generated on my page that I cannot control contains an alert. Is there a jQuery or other way to disable alert() from working?

The javascript that is being generated that I want to disable/modify is:

```
function fndropdownurl(val)
1317 { var target_url
1318 target_url = document.getElementById(val).value;
1319 if (target_url == 0)
1320 {
1321 alert("Please Select from DropDown")
1322 }
1323 else
1324 {
1325 window.open(target_url);
1326 return;
1327 }
1328 }
```

I want to disable the alert on line 1321

Thanks

Comment: See [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Simply overwrite `alert` with your own, empty, function.

```
window.alert = function() {};

// or simply
alert = function() {};
```

Comment: The second version won't work in IE. Stick to the first.

Comment: The first one works cross-browsers, Thanks!

Comment: how to enable it again?

Comment: @NkSP I think you might be able to re-enable it by running `delete window.alert` or just `delete alert` (both worked for me in Chrome console). I think that would remove your empty function and leave the native function working as expected.

Comment: `delete window.alert` doesn't work for me, but this yes it does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10267075/454827

Answer (score 21):

This works in Chrome and other browsers with the `console.log` function.

```
window.alert = function ( text ) { console.log( 'tried to alert: ' + text ); return true; };
alert( new Date() );
// tried to alert: Wed Dec 08 2010 14:58:28 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Comment: Indeed, if you avoid the default behavior of alert() it is a good idea to at least output alert() calls to console.log(). Just overriding alerts puts you on a much more obscure scenario. Your code can fail and because you supressed al alerts (that may contain important info) you may be never acknolowedged. Cool.

Answer (score 9):

You can try and make a new function `function alert() { }` , this is not going to do anything since is empty and will overwrite the existing one.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
alert("test");
alert = function(){};
alert("test");
```

The second line assigns a new blank function to alert, while not breaking the fact that it is a function. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9MHzL/