# Is there a way to clone native functions in javascript like window.alert or document.write

Tags: javascript, function, clone, native-methods

What I want to do is change every alert in the code to a custom alert("you used alert");

```
var hardCodedAlert = alert; //I know this won't work.But what to do ?
window.alert=function(){
if(this.count == undefined)
this.count=0;
this.count=this.count+1;
if(this.count == 1)
hardCodedAlert("You used alert");
};
```

Comment: Try running your code. You'll be surprised... ))

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/RM2XR/), why did you "know this won't work"?

Comment: window.alert() and document.wite() are not native - they are browser extensions to the ECMA standard

Comment: @thg435 yeah I am surprised :)
Well, alert is a function(object).AFAIK objects are copied by reference .So change in alert function will be reflected in hardCodedAlert function also.So "You used Alert" alert should not have come.

Comment: Yes, but your code doesn't _change_ `alert` itself - it's simply not possible. It just binds the name "alert" to a new function.

Comment: @ValRedchenko 
Thanks for pointing out.You are right.I thought they may be native cause toString function on these objects print [native code].

Comment: @thg435 So what you mean is the whole thing about changing the source code of a function in javascript is wrong.Javascript just associates the name to a new function and calls new function in place of original function ?

Comment: @thg435 thanks +1 for this :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do (for example):

```
var oldalert = window.alert;
window.alert= function alert(t){
  alert.count = !alert.count ? 1 : alert.count + 1;
  oldalert(t+' - That\'s alert nr '+alert.count);
};
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/YK6ca/)