# Prevent OpenCPU javascript error popup window

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, opencpu

I have an error related to CORs for a test deployment of OpenCPU, which may get its own question, but for now I'd like it to fail without notifying the end user via a popup - is this possible?

The error I see in the browser console is due to the website swapping TLD as you navigate:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://104.XX.3.XX/ocpu/library/predict/R/. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.XXXX.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.XXXX.dk' is therefore not allowed access.`

And a popup appears:

[image]

I'd like to ensure if there are possible future errors it doesn't detract for the user experience - in this case OpenCPU is used for a non-essential function of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Found via a non-specific to [OpenCPU question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388248/disable-alert)

`// suppress alerts
window.alert = function ( text ) { console.log( 'tried to alert: ' + text ); return true; };`