# How to accept alert that is triggered by 'get' in selenium (python, chromedriver)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium to navigate from some page to another:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("...some page...")
...  # the alert does not exist yet and thus cannot be accepted
driver.get("...some other page...") # the alert pops up here and blocks navigation to 'some other page'
# execution never reaches here
...
```

Now, navigating away from 'some page' triggers an alert, asking to confirm that one really wants to leave the page. This blocks execution forever. An implicit timeout was set, but is not triggered by this. I cannot get selenium to accept the alert, because only appears after calling 'get'.

Is there any way around this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why you cannot accept alert? Show code how you try to accept it

Comment: I cannot accept the alert, because it only appears after calling `get`. Then execution is stuck. So I can neither accept the alert before calling `get`, because it does not exist yet, nor afterwards, because execution never gets past the `get`

Comment: However, you can accept this alert. So how you try to accept it? Show us code sample you use

Comment: i'll change the question to make it clearer

Comment: I added some comments to the code in the question. Is this clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code and let me know if it's not working

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("...some page...")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Alert not found. Move on...)
driver.get("...some other page...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does not solve it though, because the alert does not pop up until `driver.get("...some other page...")`.

Comment: so use `try/except` block not after `driver.get("...some page...")`, but after `driver.get("...some other page...")`

Comment: this won't work either, because execution just stops at `driver.get("...some other page")` (it seems to be blocked by the alert) and therefore would not reach the `try/except` block

Comment: Have you tried it or it's just your suggestion? Script execution cannot be blocked by alert!

Comment: You're right. Turns out that the problem was somewhere else and I jumped to conclusions. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again for your help! In the end it lead me to the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388248/disable-alert) the `javascript` `alert` function.

```
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259660/how-to-accept-alert-that-is-triggered-by-get-in-selenium-python-chromedriver#40259660')
wmd_input = ref_settings.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'wmd-input')
wmd_input.click()
wmd_input.send_keys('That's a test for a model JS dialog')

#the following line overwrites the alert function
driver.execute_script("""window.alert = function() {};alert = function() {};""")
time.sleep(3)
ref_settings.driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```