# Disabling alert/popup for Android Webview ChromeClient

Tags: android, popup, android-webview

I am working on an app which has an activity/fragment that displays web pages for certain sites. Android webview (chrome) is popping up alert dialogs for subscribing to push notifications in some of them, which is causing weird flashing/flickering issue.

This is the section for webview and it's settings

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath("");
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(mUserAgent);

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            BaseWebViewFragment.this.onReceivedTitle(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            progressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
```

I need to disable these popups completely but cannot find a way to do it.

I tried disabling JS completely, but it causes loading issue for some of the sites.

I also tried overriding the onJS...() methods for WebChromeClient and canceling/confirming the result but to no avail.

Whats the working approach for this?

Comment: did you develop the web site ? or you know the developer who built this ?

Comment: It's a news site that pops up a chrome push notification alert dialog.

Comment: did you try onJsPrompt and return true ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the onJs... methods and it's already specified in the question.

Comment: could you share your code, just overriding  onJS...() method part ?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a page that does this. Do you have an example site? Also, does it still happen if you use WebViewClient instead of WebChromeClient?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7395170/6432826) you should get html as string and insert [this script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388248/disable-alert) in its head

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    window.alert = function() {};
  </script>
```

so if your html string is *htmlStr*, it's something like this:

```
String script = "<script type = \"text/javascript\">\n" +
                "        window.alert = function() {}\n" +
                "      </script>";
String target = "<head>";

int ind = htmlStr.indexOf(target);
StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder(htmlStr);
htmlBuilder.insert(ind + target.length(), script);
String newHtml = htmlBuilder.toString();
```

and then load the *newHtml* into WebView by something like this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, newHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```