# How do you close an alert dialog with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

To me it seems like this would be easy to Google for, but I'm not finding anything. I've searched:

- jquery click alert
- jquery submit alert
- jquery click popup
- jquery submit popup
- jQuery click modal dialog
- jQuery submit modal dialog
- jQuery click confirmation
- jQuery submit confirmation

And so on. I fully expect for this to be closed as a duplicate, but I'm listing my searches out so that it can help the next person: maybe it will lead to the answer I couldn't find on my own and save them some time.

That aside, here is the context. I am writing a greasemonkey/tapermonkey userscript that clicks on a button and that button has an event on it that brings up a `confirm()`. How do I click on the "OK" or "Cancel" button of that confirm popup?

Comment: `window.confirm` is pretty easy, but that's quite different from jQuery modals, for which it'll be hard to say without seeing the code the site uses (there are many, many ways for the site to implement this...)

Comment: Only the user can do this.

Comment: I imagine there's a chance this isn't possible because the thread may block when the alert is up.

Comment: @ChrisG Even with a greasemonkey script?

Comment: A greasemonkey script runs JS code but JS cannot click on alert boxes.

Comment: @DanielKaplan nope. Since it's "painted" in the OS layer outside of JS reach. Imagine a Popup asking: "This site is asking to access your camera. Allow access?" and JS clicking on OK :D

Comment: Ah... so where do we go now? Do I wait for somebody to answer, "You can't do this," and accept it?

Comment: There are always ways around it, but without seeing the code the site uses, it's not really possible to answer

Comment: @ChrisG with greasemonkey, would it be easy to modify the event so it doesn't bring up a popup anymore?

Comment: You can try something like `window.alert = console.log;`

Comment: And BTW, FYI popups and alerts are slowly being deprecated. Let me find an article....

Comment: Duplicate: [Disable alert();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388248/disable-alert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site uses `window.confirm` (regardless of whether it also uses jQuery or not), you can overwrite it and implement your own functionality. For example:

```js
// userscript code
window.confirm = () => true;

// site code
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const result = confirm('did you really mean to click the button?');
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

You cannot use a userscript to interact with any of the `window.alert`, `window.confirm`, or `window.prompt` modals, but

- such modals are very bad practice, so hopefully you won't see them often anyway
- all of these methods can be tweaked with a userscript by overwriting them, like in the above snippet, so that the browser modal doesn't come up at all.