# creating the alert() method without the display - javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

is there a way that I can duplicate what the alert() function does, without the popup?? This might seem mad but there is good cause for this.

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
var navActive;
var pageID;
var maxNav;
var popWidth = $(window).width();
var popHeight = $(window).height();

function thread_start(callback) {

   setTimeout(callback, 1);
   return true;
}

(function($){

$.fn.foneySlide = function ( options ) {

    $(window).resize(function(){
        popWidth = $(window).width() - 40;
        popHeight = $(window).height() - 40;
    })

    opt = $.extend ({ popOnTransition : true }, options);

    // firstly give all navigation items a position reference for continous slide
    $('[data-role=page]').each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('navpos', i );
        if( typeof $('[data-role=page]')[i+1] == 'undefined' ) {
            maxNav = i;
        }
    });

    // get the current active page and the default navigation position
    pageID = $('.ui-page-active').attr('id');
    navActive = $('#' + pageID).attr('navpos');

    // change page on swipe left       
    $('body').bind('swipeleft', function(e){
        if( navActive == maxNav ) {
            navActive = 0;
            alert();
            thread_start("$.mobile.changePage($('[navpos=0]'), 'slide', false, true)");
        }else{
            navActive = Number(navActive + 1);
            alert();
            thread_start("$.mobile.changePage($('[navpos=' + navActive  + ']'), 'slide', false, true)");
        }
    });

    // change page on swipe right                
    $('body').bind('swiperight', function(e){
        if( navActive == 0 ) {
            navActive = maxNav;
            alert();
            thread_start("$.mobile.changePage($('[navpos=' + navActive + ']'), 'slide', true, true)");
        }else{
            navActive = Number(navActive - 1);
            alert();
            thread_start("$.mobile.changePage($('[navpos=' + navActive  + ']'), 'slide', true, true)");
        }
    }); 
}
```

})(jQuery);

remove the alerts and it starts to freeze.

Comment: What is alert without the popup?

Comment: What does the alert function do, without the popup?

Comment: Assuming that all an alert does is display a popup, I wonder what would be the expected result if you don't want the popup. It's like taking the sun away from a summer holiday. You are left with, nothing :-)

Comment: Thats a good question. I'm creating a mobile page slider plugin for small websites on mobile devices that do not need a navigation (because of space) so they can siomply slide finger across to go to next page. The jqueryMobile $.mobile.ChangePage() function freezes on most devices and does not work once the user has scrolled down (from what I have tested). If I stick alert() beforehande after the slideLeft event is triggered and I close the alert box everything slides nicely.

Comment: So I wonder what the alert() function does behind the scenes.

Comment: @Phil, that is using a sideeffect of something completely unrelated to hack something not working in your app. You should a) fix the script and b) tell jQuery mobile if you are certain you found a bug

Comment: So we now understand that Phil just wants to block the script for a millisecond.

Comment: This is a good question, I would really like to know what window.alert() does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one single use for alert, and that is showing a popup, so I wonder what that cause is. ..  :)

But it is possible, as demonstrated [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert).

```
function alert(msg)
{
  // Ignore
}
```

Comment: I think it is as easy as the sample I've just added. The global context in javascript is actually inside the window object, so redeclaring the alert function will override it.

Comment: But if you get specific errors it would be helpful if you posted your code and the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are after but I use firebug and the console.log call a lot to get information about what the javascript is doing without interfering with the site flow.

remember however to bypass the console.log method if it is a live site as anyone without firebug will receive errors.

```
if(typeof console == 'undefined') {
    console = function(){}
    console.log = function(txt){}
    console.warn = function(txt){}
} else console.log('Console Active');
```

[Get Firebug site](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments but not knowing  your code, is this what you are trying to achieve?

before:

```
function something() {
  a();
  b(); // needs a pause before executing c()
  c();
}
```

after:

```
function something() {
  a();
  b(); // needs a pause before executing c()
  setTimeout(c,10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.alert = function(text) { }
```