# Replace alert window

Tags: javascript, alert

I use in my project third-party **obfuscated** JS library. The matter is it uses standard alert window for notifications. My task is to replace this browser alert window with my custom. My solution is:

```
alert = function(msg) {
    customAlert(msg);
}
```

Is there any another, may be better way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible by overriding `window.alert`:

```
window.alert = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Of course, it goes without saying that, if the library has already grabbed a reference to `alert`, it will be much harder to override (ex, because it has used `(function() { var myalert = window.alert; … myalert("foo"); })()`)…