# Change JS alerts to show/hide jQuery alert div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title is confusing, so I'll elaborate..

I am working on a FaceBook box for my website, and when the comment is successfully posted, it displays an `alert()`. I am wanting to get rid of the `alert()` and instead, via jQuery, show and then fade out a div which will say the same thing as the `alert()` box.

Here's my code:

```
}, function (response) {
    if (response == 0) {
    alert("Your FaceBook status has not been updated.");
    } else {
        alert("Your FaceBook status has been updated.");
    }
    showLoader(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can replace the native alert() functionality, you can not achieve the blocking effect that the browser's native alert() provides.

I suggest something like [this](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/), or take a look at **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)**.

Comment: While I like this, I wanted to display a message over the text box and then have the message fade out. This way everything's inline. Do you know of any scripts like this?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I'm looking for. I've set up a jsFiddle trying to accomplish this, can you figure out what I did wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/f8eDj/2/

Comment: It appears GitHub is preventing you from hotlinking the script like that, since its throwing a 403 forbidden. Try placing the block script on your own server instead.

Comment: Looks like it's working. Now I would just put that code as a substitute for both the `alert()` functions above?

Comment: Just to follow up on this, it was solved by calling this, `$('#container').block({ message: 'Your FaceBook status has been updated.', timeout: 10000,  });`, when it meets the `if` requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://thrivingkings.com/sticky/
or http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/