# Can somebody provide me the official link where its writeen that a person can not change the default alert box of ie

Tags: javascript, windows

Can somebody provide me the official link where its written that a person can not change the default alert box of ie

Comment: No, because there probably isn't such a link. You cannot change it because *no way is provided to change it* not because *they say it can't be changed*.

Comment: Not sure if it's "officially" written anywhere....you just can't do it.

Comment: You can override alert(); and replace it with whatever html UI you like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Comment: because it is browser related functionality,,just we can invoke that's all

Comment: @AlexK..is there a way to do it by javascript....because the link you provided here gives implementation in jquery

Comment: @rcky the accepted answer does not need jQuery; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/hnnFx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the "Remarks" in the [MSDN page about `window.alert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Given that "You cannot change the title bar of the Alert dialog box." is what Microsoft have to say about it that should be "official" enough for you.

(Having said that, `window.alert()` takes one parameter, the message, so obviously that's the only configurable thing.)

Comment: @nnnnnn..thanks , by the way i too got the same link  before you posted

Answer (score 1):

An official link is not necessary. You cannot change it for security reasons. However, you can create your own custom alert/notification box using a bit of jQuery if you really wish.

Comment: @Prowla...........instead of jquery , can you suggest some other way.

Comment: @Prowla........what i need is javascript.......can you help me in that

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library- "The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library". Is there any reason why you wish to avoid using jQuery?

Comment: @ Prowla.......yes there are project specific reasons.....