# JavaScript external script alert() function not working

Tags: javascript

I have something simple. I have an html file and JavaScript file. In the JavaScript file the simple `alert()` function is called but, it does not work!

I wrote a second line in the JavaScript file to make sure I was not giving the incorrect path `console.log()` and it works as expected.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

    </div>

    <script src="functionality.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In external JavaScript file:

```
alert('hello'); // does not get executed
console.log( 'hello' ); // gets executed
```

Why this does not work?

Comment: There is no visible reason why it should not work. Any message in the console? Perhaps you have suppressed alerts in the browser?

Comment: Using Chrome? Have you pressed "prevent this page from creating additional dialoug" recently? Try restarting the browser.

Comment: if that's the case as @mplungjan said - then this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640361/re-enabling-window-alert-in-chrome

Comment: Yes. Console says, 'hello'

Comment: Ha! That was it! The Chrome "prevent this page from..."

Comment: Restarted browser and all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably pressed "prevent this page from creating additional dialog" in your Chrome browser. Try restarting it.