# Simple jQuery working in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple div with basic content...

```
<div id="slide"> ... </div>
```

The following code works in FireFox but not in Chrome.  I tried accessing the .css ("width") and other properties as well with the same result.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if( $(this).width() < 900) {
    alert( $("#slide").html() );
  }
});
```

Any idea why this isn't working in Chrome?  One interesting thing is this does work in both...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if( $(this).width() < 900) {
    $("#slide").hide();
  }
});
```

My end goal is to access/change a child element in the div, but that wasn't working, so I tried to the access to the div itself for a sanity check...and no luck in Chrome.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, see [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/comunamopa/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Are you sure you haven't checked "prevent additional dialogs" checkbox in Chrome when the alert first popped up? Try clearing browser cache and settings. Also avoid using `alert()`, use `console.log()` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640361/re-enabling-window-alert-in-chrome

Comment: What version of chrome are you running? Have you tried updating?

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me...

> Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

```
var slide = $("#slide");

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() < 900){
       alert(slide.html());
    }
})
```

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e28Lnv5t/1/

Comment: Thanks the jsfiddle example helped me work things out.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

HTML:

```
<p>Minimize the screen and look different</p>

<div id="slide">TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slide{
  border: solid thin #bebebe;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() < 900){
    $("#slide").hide();
  }
})
```