# java script function disable using coding permanently

Tags: javascript, php

> Blockquote

i want to disable java script checked box

'prevent this page from creating additional dialog'

permanently using coding.

please suggest me the right function

> Blockquote

Comment: As referenced before, you can't do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729835/how-to-disable-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs

The best thing you can do is create your own html/css alert.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend but You can not do this.

The javascript popup is a browser feature there to prevent sites from showing multiple alerts to prevent you from leaving.