# How to create while loop with alert and prompt to avoid empty input?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I want to create a while loop to avoid empty input. Here's my code, I want it to loop so that the user gets the same alert and then prompt window until he/she writes a name/username. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
confirm("Wanna play?");
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
while (name.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    prompt("What's your name?");
}
else {
    document.write("Welcome to my game " + name + "!" + "<br>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Renan suggested it right. Still, if you need the current code to work, you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
confirm("Wanna play?");
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
while (name.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    name = prompt("What's your name?");
}
document.write("Welcome to my game " + name + "!" + "<br>");
</script>
```

There are some errors in your code/logic:

1. Why is there `else` after `while`? `else` is used with `if` clause only.
2. You are asking for the name in the `while` loop, but not assigning it to the `name` variable. If you do not assign to `name`, how would the `name` variable get updated and cause the `while` loop to exit?

Comment: I would just use in `if` instead of a while. In the `else` block I would have `document.write("GTFO then.")`

Comment: @Renan you would use a function to call if the name is empty repeatedly then?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: @Renan ok. But OP probably wants to create a demo for something where he needs the user to enter the name first, only then the flow should proceed.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, hi Mohit, I am beginner in Javascript and would like to ask you, I wrote: while (name.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    prompt("What's your name?");
} and removed variable name from prompt but alert("Please enter your name!"); keeps iterating. Why is that? Please help

Comment: @mirzhal did you remove this line also - `name = prompt("What's your name?");` ?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, no, only removed name=, that is, I have - prompt("What's your name?") just why need to add "name =" before prompt. I hope you got my point))

Comment: @mirzhal yeah that explains it. You are asking the user for a name, but not storing his input anywhere. So, the `name` variable is still empty, when the while condition is checked again and so it goes in the loop again and it keeps looping. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

**Never abuse `prompt`, `alert` and `confirm` in your pages.**

I could write a lot about this but I will just leave this image here.

[image]

Users can easily silence your attempts to call their attention via dialogs, so any extra effort you spend on that is wasted.

Comment: Will have that in mind, but I'm currently learning how to use those methods! Learning how to code chapter by chapter.

Comment: @AnnaBannanna it's ok, I see a lot of experienced programmers that don't know about this either. This might be a bit much for now if you are just beginning, but you might like to look [at this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729835/how-to-disable-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs). There are other ways to force a user to give meaningful input to your page.

Answer (score 0):

See If this does what you're looking for!

```
confirm("Wanna play?");
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
while (name.length == 0) {
    name = prompt("Please, insert a name to proceed!");
}
document.write("Welcome to my game " + name + "!" + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```js
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
while (name.length == 0 || name == "null" || name == null) {
    name = prompt("What's your name");
}
```