# How to write JavaScript function like prompt/confirm

Tags: javascript

I want to write a JavaScript function like `prompt()` or `confirm()` where line execution wait until the mentioned function returned anything.

Say, I have a function `abc()` which will open a popup and then return a value. I want to hold the execution where the function was called.

```
function abc(){
    //----------
    return '';
}

function abc_caller(){
    var x = abc();
    alert(x);
}
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: *Possible duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729684/1563422

Comment: Make your function do something that keeps the control and doesn't return it back

Comment: @DannyBeckett Not really. I think the OP actually wants to write a synchronous function that **blocks**.

Comment: That's not how you design API asking for user input in JavaScript : the user thread must release control which means no function can be blocking. Any decent API will require a callback that will be called upon user action.

Comment: This question is based on a bad understanding on how a JavaScript program must be designed. You must understand event based programming before designing your API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be -

```
function abc_caller(){
       var x = abc();
       var r=confirm("Your value is " + x);
       if (r==true)
       {
          alert("You pressed OK!")
       }
       else
       {
          alert("You pressed Cancel!")
      }
    }
```

More examples in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something browser builders want you to do. If a piece of Javascript is not responding within a certain amount of time the browser will start to think something is wrong and will ask the user if he wants to stop javascript from running.

You should create a callback function instead.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer while I was typing mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You clould use callback for this:
*your function*

```
function abc(callback){
    // whatever code here
    var result = ""; // or whatever processing result would be

    if (callback)
    {
        callback(result);
    }
}
```

*usage:*

```
abc(function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

**Edit:** I think it's something similar to what @mrhobo was proposing