# How to show alert box with checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to display the alert(or something like it) box in the jquery but how can i insert the custom control inside the alert box. I want to make a database call when the user checked the checkbox.

I tried to use the following but not worked as it is only for text:

```
var name = window.prompt("prompt goes here", "text");
```

but i want to add checkbox.

Comment: ans 
you cant....you need to override implementation of prompt() ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Comment: @Pilot please explain a bit.

Comment: Please check reference question my friend

Comment: you should use jquery dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
var customDialog = function (options) {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                        .html('<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />Test Checkbox<div style="margin-top: 15px; font-weight: bold;">' + options.message + '</div>')
                        .dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            title: options.title || 'Alert Message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
};
```

and call it like this:

```
customDialog({message: 'Test Message'});
```

As you can notice in the above code, you can add any custom html in jQuery's `html` method. Here `opetions` is a javascript object literal. In the above example it is having two known properties, i.e. `message` and `title`, which you can pass while calling. You are free to customize it into any extent.

**Update:** Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knvn/c6KwS/2/) for your reference.

Comment: the msg shows on the lower left corner and then suddenly disappears

Comment: I am not sure, what issue you are facing. I have updated the answer with jsfiddle. Let me know, if you still not able to solve your problem.

Comment: i think my jquery ui refrence are not working properly'

Comment: I have down this by using Telerik Rad Alert but still accepting this answers as it worked fine.