# Disable popups and alertboxes in android webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I am using webview with javascript enables since it is required in my app fulltime.
My issue is that I need to avoid popups while loading url's in my webview is there a way to do that?

I came across the onJsAlert() method but as per androids documentation

```
 Tell the client to display a javascript alert dialog.
 If the client returns true, WebView will assume that the client will handle the dialog.
 If the client returns false, it will continue execution.
```

and this is not what i want. I want to avoid popups and alert boxes (including prompt and confirm)
any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try overriding alert,confirm, etc. Maybe add a flag on when to allow and when not to allow the alert to show.
[JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Comment: the webpage i am loading is not under my control. i cant change the code of the website.

Comment: you can attach javascript to the webview. webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hi');"). I would suggest doing it when the page is finished loading.

Comment: but that will show alert instead of avoiding it. my aim is to not show any alerts. I am sorry if my question is lame :/

Comment: :D The alert("hi") was just to show that you can attach custom javascript to the webview once its loaded. The link in my answer provides javascript on how to override the alert functionality, so you would replace alert("hi") with the code in the link.

Comment: webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.alert = function(){}");       I tried this but popup still appears.

Comment: Without knowing the specific page, they could be doing custom alerts or something else. I would suggest you verify how they are calling their alerts. You could also create a simple webpage and attempt it against that to see if it works.

Comment: thanks I am now injecting the javascirpt on every progress of page load. and Not getting any alrts thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I tried the approach described in the accepted answer, from Kalel Wade, and by injecting JavaScript on every progress event I was able to block popups. However, I found what appears to be a much more elegant approach.

If you extend WebChromeClient, you can override its onJsAlert() method and block the built-in handler for alerts. While you're at it, you will probably want to block calls to confirm() and prompt():

```
WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }
};

webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

Given that you're seeing JavaScript alerts, I believe you must have already assigned a WebChromeClient. (If you don't do so, alerts are not supported.) So it should just be a matter of adding the overrides above.

Be sure to call result.cancel() prior to returning. From my experience, if you don't do this, the JavaScript engine seems to hang; the button stays in the pressed state, and no subsequent interaction is registered.

Comment: Thanks @markproxy.
Is there also a similar solution for blocking popups in iOS, for both UIWebview & WkWebview?

Comment: Sorry @rishabh, I have no idea. I have no experience on the iOS side.

Comment: evidently if you don't use result.cancel(); webview.loadUrl and other functions starts behaving weirdly.