# Disable javascript alerts in UIWebView & WkWebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

As mentioned in this example for Android: [Disable popups and alertboxes in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138089/disable-popups-and-alertboxes-in-android-webview/37082558#37082558)

WebChromeClient can be used to block javascript alerts.

Can someone provide a similar example for blocking window.alert|window.confirm|window.prompt javascript alerts in iOS WebViews & WkWebViews?

Answer (score 0):

in wkwebview this is implicit. A js alert fires a delegate call only. an alert would have to be triggered by the objc/swift code

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan, can you please explain your answer a bit more? Have some examples in place if possible.

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan,
Understanding a bit here. Are you saying even if the javascript code is trying to trigger an alert(), the WkWebview will implictly not display the alert? But it will be upto the WkWebview managed object to intercept this somehow & throw an alert?

Answer (score 0):

@roshabh Yes,I just meet the same question, you must use UIDelegate methods of WKWebview to show the alert/conform/prompt effect.
code eg:

```
webview?.uiDelegate = self
```

extension MessageNoticeViewController: WKUIDelegate {

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("cancel", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = defaultText
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        if let text = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
            completionHandler(text)
        } else {
            completionHandler(defaultText)
        }
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("cancel", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler(nil)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}