# Webview: block JavaScript popups

Tags: javascript, android, webview, block, overlays

Right now I'm using this line of code to at least try to block popups by `JavaScript` in `webview`:

`webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`

1) I don't get it why I have to switch this to "true" that it's working
2) are there any other techniques for blocking popups in webview?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean true/false);`

Answer (score 5):

## preamble

We are at the `WebView` ***setup*** side of the equation.
At first glance an obvious comment, but if you ***don't need*** `JavaScript`, ***don't enable*** `JavaScript`, then you don't get `JavaScript` popup's. I'm assuming you **DO** need `JavaScript` (remember it *may be* [XSS vulnerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) and want to do ***what you can*** to disable the popups that ***can*** inevitably follow.

**INFO**:

[WebViewClient](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/). Override this behavior of your `WebView`, e.g. so links open within your `WebView`.
[WebChromeClient](http://therockncoder.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/understanding-androids-webchromeclient.html) lets you handle `Javascript's alert()` and other functions.
**OP(1)**`setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)` is ***usually*** blocked ***only*** when done ***outside*** of an ***event handler***.
**OP** = Original Post **;O)**.

## Let's setup a senario

This is how I setup my normal `webview`:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);//CustomWebView ?

WebSettings webView_settings = webView.getSettings();

//by setting a WebClient to catch javascript's console messages :

WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            Log.d(TAG, cm.message() + " -- From line "
                    + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                    + cm.sourceId() );
            return true;
        }
    });
webView_settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            setTitle(view.getTitle());
            //do your stuff ...
            }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("file")) 
        {
            // Keep local assets in this WebView.
             return false;
        }
      }
    });

//webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient(this));//
webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView_settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//XSS vulnerable set to false ?
webView_settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);//set to false ?
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/connect.php.html");//load something
```

## OP(2) Let's block what we can

From [@markproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138089/disable-popups-and-alertboxes-in-android-webview#37082558) If you extend `WebChromeClient`, you can override its `onJsAlert()` method and block the built-in handler for alerts. *While you're at it*, you will probably want to block calls to the `confirm()` and `prompt()`:

```
WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }
};

webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try block popups (windows) in WebChromeClient:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    WebView newWebView = (WebView) LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.webview_custom_view, null);
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(newWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    return true;
}
```

Object newWebView should add to some container like a view.It's example of creating the window (popup) from WebView.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this. Override the onJSAlert() method in the WebChromeClient class:

```
MyWebChromeClient myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
webView.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);
```

**MyWebChromeClient** is a custom Class that Inherits **WebChromeClient**

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
    {
        final JsResult finalRes = result;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finalRes.confirm();  
                        }
                    })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            .show();
        return true;
    }
}
```