# Silence Script Error in Web Browser for Android from Delphi XE7 FireMonkey

Tags: user-interface, delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to silence the error alert windows in delphi xe7 webbrowser.

Webbroser for Win:
      Webbrowser.Silent = false;

Webbrowser for Android?
.................................

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you'd need to write some Java code to include with your project, because you need to assign an instance of a descendant of WebChromeClient that overrides the onJsAlert method, as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37082558/3164070

Then you would need to create an import for that class for Delphi, create an instance of it, and pass it in a call to the setWebChromeClient method on the WebBrowser (JWebBrowser) instance in the TAndroidWebBrowserService class in the FMX.WebBrowser.Android unit i.e. you would need to modify that unit for this to all work.

A more complete answer would probably take a few hours, however this should give you an idea of what you're up against