# hijack window.print event

Tags: javascript, printing

Is there a way to listen for the window.print event and hijack it?  I've done some searching and can't find what I am looking for.   Its not so much that I want to alter the default action on window.print but that another wordpress plugin seems to have already hijacked it and I want to use it normally.

I have window.print() in my code and it is firing off the printfriendly plugin for some reason.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @delueg

The only way I can see to harness the original method is to open a new window and use the function from there.