# how to stop showing alert box after overriding alert function

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I use this code for overriding alert function but after i use this to show my custom alert box it show both of them how can i stop the default alert box ? use preventDefault();
? where?

```
(function(event) {

  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function(str) {
    bootbox.alert(str);
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Comment: why return proxied.apply(this, arguments);?

Comment: i see this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Comment: Well it does seem to [override alert](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/tm78x12k/). Can you reproduce the issue..?

Comment: get rid of `return proxied.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: thanks this line of code makes issue return proxied.apply(this, arguments);

Answer (score 0):

Your code for overriding the default `alert function`, contains another alert function `bootbox.alert(str);` due to which it goes into infinite loop showing `too much recursion error.`
You could try below proxy pattern for overriding.

```
(function(event) {

  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function(str) {
   //Your code here
   proxied.apply(this, arguments);
   return true;
  };
})();
```