# Can we override the inbuilt functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, alert

I have plenty of pages on my website with javascript embeded in them.
`alert()` which is a javascript function has been used in all my scripts atleast once. I want to use custom alert box which will render same in all the browser.
I can define my own function like

```
function customAlert()
{
    // Code goes here.
}
```

But have to replace `alert()` with`customAlert()` in all my web pages which is a  time consuming process.

Instead can't we just modify native alert function accordingly and it reflects the same as in all browsers.

I think we can't use this

```
function alert()
{
    // Code goes here.
}
```

because alert is a reserved javascript word for function name.

If there is a better way for implementing the same with different technique, then feel free to answer.

> I hate to use jquery or any other frameworks library so please answer regarding pure javascript.

Comment: `alert` is not a reserved word and it is not even part of the JavaScript standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Answer (score 2):

The `alert` is a property of the global `window` object, thus you can override it in the following way:

```
window.alert = function (message){
    //do your code
};
```

and then use it the way you used it before:

```
alert('hi');
```

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle example for it?