# JavaScript detect alert and stop it from showing

Tags: javascript, alert

I am using a 3rd party js that shows `alert`'s to the user, is there a way to catch the alert before it is displayed, and show something else instead? example:

```
function doOtherPeopleCode(){
   sdk.doStuff(); //catch all sdk alerts
}
```

Comment: override window.alert in your code

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert

Comment: @Phiter - the source code is a 'closed box' without overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply replace the `window.alert` method with your custom version. Inside this replacement you can add some checks and conditions and then decide if you want to call the cached version of `window.alert` (which you store in a variable) or do something else.

Comment: We should have known this was a duplicate. I've deleted my answer, recommend doing the same.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would not agree that it is an exact duplicate, since the duplicate talks about overriding alert and this one here asks about catching an alert before it happens. Overriding is just one way of doing it.

Comment: @Phiter: There's no other vaguely-reasonable way to do it within the constraints the OP listed. The answers to the linked question answer this question. That's not even a close call by SO's duplicate rules.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As phiter said it is exact duplicate, the source for the alert is different but fill free to downvote....

Comment: BTW - is there a way to access the alert text I just overwrited? `this` inside shows the window.

Comment: @itsik the text would be the first argument provided to the method