# Overriding alert - access original text

Tags: javascript, alert

Following [overriding-alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, I have overwritten all alerts:

```
window.alert = function() {
    // access text
    console.log(this);
};
```

Is there a way to access the original alert(the overwritten that I catched) text? `this` shows the `window` object.

Comment: [It's right there in the answers to the question you linked.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730509/157247)

Comment: Yes, thanks, not sure how I missed it.

Comment: You should be able to delete the question now (it only has one answer -- posted after it was closed, *sigh*) but the score on that answer is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.alert = function(attribute) {
   // access text
   console.log(attribute);
};
```