# Is there a way to ban alerts?

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

I have many JavaScript functions for a program, all of which contain `alert`s notifying the user of certain things. I wanted to give the user the option to ban all of those alerts, without having to rewrite all of the functions without the alerts. Is there a way to ban `alert`? Maybe something like this:

```
<button onclick = "alertBan()">Alert Ban</button>
```

```
function alertBan(){
     alerts = false;
}
```

Comment: quick & dirty: `const alertBan = ()=>{};` override the `alertBan` function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign an empty function to `alert`.

```
function alertBan(){
     alert = function(){};
}
```

If you might need to reenable alerts later on, you can store `window.alert` in a variable when the page loads.

```
const oldAlert = alert;
function alertBan(){
     alert = function(){};
}
function enableAlerts(){
    alert = oldAlert;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the original alert for perhaps later use. Replace the alert through empty function or with setted parameter to write on console.
If need the normal alert back take the stored one back.

```js
alertOrig = alert;
function alertBan(consoleLog){
    alert = function(e) {
        if (consoleLog) console.log(e);
    }
}

function alertEnable(){
   if ( alertOrig )
       alert=alertOrig;
}

alertBan();
alert('No console + no alert');

alertBan(true);
alert('With console');

alertEnable();
alert('Normal alert');
```